# scrollViewDidEndDecelerating detect which collection view in action

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I use this method to organize paging:

```
- scrollViewDidEndDecelerating
```

When I scroll my `UICollectionView` I change some content on my screen. But I have few UICollectionView on my screen and I need it just for one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, so you could just check which scroll view did end decelerating from within the delegate method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == collectionViewOne) {

    }else if (scrollView == collectionViewTwo) {

    }else{
            //something else
    }
}
```